# Foreach loop returns data after exucation

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

```
<?php 
$x = 1; 

while($x <= 5) {
    echo "The number is: $x <br>";
    $x++;
} 
?>
```

On my localhost server i see while it executes but on another server i see the echo after it executes?

Anyone knows what's the mistake?

Comment: Most likely output buffering is in effect.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Any chance how i can close it?